# How can I render full chart using PhantomJS?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, phantomjs

I'm trying to get the image of highcharts chart from webpage. 
Using PhantomJS I can export chart to file, but it's not full. I don't know why but PhantomJS render only small part of the chart.

[image: Chart capture]

For rendering I'm using this code:

```
page.clipRect = page.evaluate(function() {  
     return document.querySelector('#container').getBoundingClientRect();
    }); 

page.render(output);
```

What I'm doing wrong and how can I get entire chart?

Comment: Can you verify that animations are disabled?

Comment: you may need to wait a little until you graph is completely rendered

Comment: Thanks, the problem was solved! I disable highchart animation and then phantomjs render correct chart!

Answer (score 3):

Seems like animation has not been disabled. Try setting `animation: false` to chart.

*Edit: Seems like [@eric](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1102962/eric) has already answered this as comment.*

Comment: Thanks) Yes Eric already told me about this idea and it's works fine)